# Order of the splitting field of $f(x)$ with $\deg f(x)=11$ over $\Bbb F_p$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Given $f(x)\in\Bbb F_5[x]$ with $\deg f(x)=11$ for example.  Suppose that $f(x)$ is irreducible. We know that the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb F_5$ must exist, and its degree is $\le11!$. Generally speaking, $\Bbb F_{5^3}$ may not be big enough to contain all the roots of $f(x)$, and so does, say $\Bbb F_{5^{11}}$. So my question is that, what is the "biggest" possible order of the finite field we need to contains all of its root? I can only bound it by $5^{11!}$, but I think it may be strictly smaller. Are there some theorems related to this?

**Update:** Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb F_5$. Then by a theorem of finite field, $K=\Bbb F_5(u)$. If we can choose such $u$ as a root of $f(x)$, then since the degree of the minimal polynomial of $u$ is less then $11$, $[K:\Bbb F_5]\leq 11$. Then it seems that $\Bbb F_{5^{11}}$ is quite enough?

Comment: If $k=\Bbb F_q$ is a finite field, and $f$ an irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ over $k$, then its splitting field is $\Bbb F_{q^d}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So is the theoretic upper bound $5^{11!}$? (And there must exist such $f(x)$ for instance.)

Comment: Yes, over every finite field there are irreducible polynomials of every degree.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb F_5$. Then $K=\Bbb F_5(u)$. If we can choose such $u$ as a root of $f(x)$, then since the degree of the minimal polynomial of $u$ is less then $11$, $[K:\Bbb F_5]\leq 11$. Then it seems that $\Bbb F_{5^{11}}$ is quite enough to contain all the roots of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One knows that every extension of finite fields $\Bbb F_q\subset K$ is Galois with Galois group cyclic generated by the Frobenius morphism $x\mapsto x^q$.

Comment: Make that $x^q$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Wow, that was quick! :) Corrected